# Multivariable Taylor expansion give incorrect answer

Tags: series-expansion

I have a matrix
$M(\text{kx$\_$},\text{ky$\_$})=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_2 (1-\cos (\text{kx}) \cos (\text{ky}))+a_1 (1-\cos (\text{kx})) & 2 a_2 \sin (\text{kx}) \sin (\text{ky}) \\
 2 a_2 \sin (\text{kx}) \sin (\text{ky}) & a_2 (1-\cos (\text{kx}) \cos (\text{ky}))+a_1 (1-\cos (\text{ky})) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
M[kx_, ky_] = ({
{Subscript[a, 1] (1 - Cos[kx]) + 
  Subscript[a, 2] (1 - Cos[kx] Cos[ky]), 
 2 Subscript[a, 2] Sin[kx] Sin[ky]},
{2 Subscript[a, 2] Sin[kx] Sin[ky], 
 Subscript[a, 1] (1 - Cos[ky]) + 
  Subscript[a, 2] (1 - Cos[kx] Cos[ky])}
 });
```

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors at the limit of kx$\to$0 and ky$\to$0 in any direction of $\vec k$.

If I define ky=0

```
In[57]:= Eigensystem[M[kx, 0]]

Out[57]= {{(-1 + Cos[kx]) (-Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, 
     2]), -(-1 + Cos[kx]) Subscript[a, 2]}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}
```

Eigenvalue is $(a_1+a_2) (1-\cos (\text{kx})),a_2 (1-(\cos (\text{kx}))$

In the limit, it is  $(a_1+a_2)\text{kx}^2/2,a_2 \text{kx}^2/2$

If I define kx=0

```
In[58]:= Eigensystem[M[0, ky]]

Out[58]= {{(-1 + Cos[ky]) (-Subscript[a, 1] - Subscript[a, 
     2]), -(-1 + Cos[ky]) Subscript[a, 2]}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}
```

Eigenvalue is $(a_1+a_2) (1-\cos (\text{ky})),a_2 (1-(\cos (\text{kx}))$

In the limit, it is  $(a_1+a_2) \text{ky}^2/2,a_2\text{kx}^2/2$

The problem occurs when I series expand Eigenvalue of $M(\text{kx},\text{ky})$

```
In[61]:= Series[Eigensystem[M[kx, ky]], {kx, 0, 2}, {ky, 0, 2}, 
 Assumptions -> {Subscript[a, 1] > 0, Subscript[a, 2] > 0, kx > 0, 
 ky > 0}]
```

It gives eigenvalues

$\left(\frac{a_2 \text{ky}^2}{2}+O\left(\text{ky}^3\right)\right)+\text{kx}^2 \left(\left(-\frac{8 a_2^2}{a_1}+\frac{a_2}{2}+\frac{a_1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2 a_2^2}{a_1}-\frac{a_2}{4}\right) \text{ky}^2+O\left(\text{ky}^3\right)\right)+O\left(\text{kx}^3\right)$

and

$\left(\left(\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{2}\right) \text{ky}^2+O\left(\text{ky}^3\right)\right)+\text{kx}^2 \left(\left(\frac{8 a_2^2}{a_1}+\frac{a_2}{2}\right)+\left(-\frac{2 a_2^2}{a_1}-\frac{a_2}{4}\right) \text{ky}^2+O\left(\text{ky}^3\right)\right)+O\left(\text{kx}^3\right)$

It agree with previous answer in the direction of kx=0 but disagree in the direction of ky=0

If I do series expansion with the order of $\{\text{ky},0,2\},\{\text{kx},0,2\}$, it becomes opposite.

What causes this bug and how can I get the correct answer?

---

**Update**
I rewrite to matrix in polar coordinate k and $\theta_k$ 
and series expand only to k. It is correct this time, but problem still remain in cartesian coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables $a$ & $b$ instead of subscripts, we calculate the eigenvalues for 3 different conditions.

```
M[kx_, ky_] := ({{a (1 - Cos[kx]) + b (1 - Cos[kx] Cos[ky]), 
     2 a Sin[kx] Sin[ky]}, {2 a Sin[kx] Sin[ky], 
     a (1 - Cos[ky]) + b (1 - Cos[kx] Cos[ky])}});
M[kx, ky] // MatrixForm

q1 = Eigenvalues[M[kx, 0]];
q2 = Eigenvalues[M[0, ky]];
q3 = Eigenvalues[M[kx, ky]];
```

We can do the usual series expansion on the first 2 sets of eigenvalues

```
s1 = Collect[Normal@Series[q1, {kx, 0, 2}], kx];
s2 = Collect[Normal@Series[q2, {ky, 0, 2}], ky];
```

But, for the third set of eigenvalues we use this trick to get its series expansion

```
s3 = Collect[Normal@Series[
           q3 /. kx -> kx*z /. ky -> ky*z, {z, 0, 2}] /. z -> 1,
      {kx, ky}];
```

Now we can take the limits of `s3` to obtain `s1` and `s2`

```
t1 = Simplify@PowerExpand@Limit[s3, ky -> 0];
t2 = Simplify@PowerExpand@Limit[s3, kx -> 0];
```

`t1` and `t2` are the same eigenvalues are `s1` and `s2`, but in a different order

```
{Sort[s1] == Sort[t1],
  Sort[s2] == Sort[t2]} // Simplify

(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Comment: Great answer! The "z" parameter trick.  Can you tell me what is your mathmetica version? Mine is 11.3. When I run your code, t1 and t2 contain kx^2 or ky^2 term. It is different with your result. Others are all fine.

Comment: @p.s  My version is "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)".  I get the same result with "11.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)" and with "10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)".  However, my results with "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" are different.  The 11.3 results contain `kx^4` and `ky^4`.

Comment: @p.s  I also get the `kx^4` and `ky^4` results with both "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" and "11.3.0 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (May 23, 2018)", so it's not a MS Windows thing.